# HTML/CSS: Place texts or objects over table column/border

Tags: html, css

I need help on how can I achieve a table similar to the one below, specifically on placing texts/objects over the table column/border. Thank you.

[image]

In case you're wondering, table is from https://www.kma.go.kr/eng/weather/forecast/timeseries.jsp

Comment: as you can see on the website you're linking to, elements are simply shifted to the left using some negative value for 'left' (position:relative, left:-11px). what exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Thank you schellmax , that's what I was looking for. I should've realized that the solution was already in front of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Relative Position (space left behind). eg.
   `{position:relative; left:-20px}`
2. Negative Margin (no space left behind). eg.
   `{margin-left: -20px;}`